# Outlook archives for mobile and home

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, archiving

I have moved my Outlook archive files to a file server because my new laptop with an SSD doesn't have enough storage to store them locally. The problem is that when I am away from home base the laptop cannot attach to the file server so Outlook is unable to open the archives.  When Outlook starts up at a remote location I get a file dialog prompting for the location of the missing archive files.  I can simply close those dialogs and Outlook will open without them.  The problem is that this is very time consuming.

I have tried defining a mobile profile with the same accounts as my default profile but without the archive files but removing the archive files from the mobile profile also removes it from the default.

It would seem that this is a common enough problem that there would be a way to do it but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks,
hkc

Comment: Have you considered a larger SSD?  I keep my Outlook archives on my laptop so I have them when I am away

Comment: Yeah, I considered a larger SSD but it would require the better part of a day to turn of bitlocker, clone the drive, swap the drives, re-enable bitlocker.  And doing it myself might void my warranty which is still active or not doing it myself will cost 4x the price of the SSD on the open market if I have to buy it from Dell.  But I may still do that when the warranty expires.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the expected behavior, [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-make-outlook-stop-asking-for-an-archive/b81c16f1-6777-4d7c-af80-6b1969f8b199) discussed the similar scenario.

An archive is not a Backup, it's a moving process where you delete the originals.Also, you can't move a pst-file while it is still connected to Outlook. The proper way is to disconnect it first via File-> Account Settings-> Account Settings...-> tab Data Files. Then close Outlook and then you can move the file to a location of your choice.

You moved it before disconnecting it from Outlook, so Outlook still expects the file to be in its location which it is not and therefore prompts you for the location.

And as you said that: your new laptop doesn't have enough storage to store them locally. So I would suggest you enable online archive(also known as in-place archive) to store the messages in server side.
In-Place Archiving in Exchange Server helps you regain control of your organization's messaging data by eliminating the need for personal store (.pst) files and allowing users to store messages in an archive mailbox. The archive mailbox is an additional mailbox that's enabled for a user's primary mailbox. The archive mailbox is accessible in Outlook and Outlook on the web (formerly known as Outlook Web App).

For mailboxes in on-prem Exchange server: [In-Place Archiving in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/in-place-archiving/in-place-archiving?view=exchserver-2019)

For O365 mailboxes: [Exchange Online Archiving service description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-archiving-service-description/exchange-online-archiving-service-description)

Comment: First of all, I did disconnect the .pst files before moving them so after moving they all work correctly when I am at home.  When I am mobile I am not able to connect to the file server that now holds the .pst files so Outlook wants to be told where they are.  This starts a time and click consuming interaction that I think is unnecessary.  I don't mind the archive function being unavailable when I am roaming.
As for using online archiving I'd rather not have my email available to 3rd parties for analysis.